# How do I delete folders from the Windows 7 DriverStore?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, graphics-tablet

I am having a problem getting a specific device to work, and I am trying to start from square one by making sure there are absolutely no leftover files from driver installs on my system. Specifically I'm trying to get rid of the UC-Logic drivers for a Monoprice 10x6 tablet.

However, I have found copies of the driver files in the windows DriverStore\FileRepository. But windows will not let me delete any folders from that location.

The best info I have found so far is to use pnputil.exe, however, since the drivers are not currently installed, it is not listed as an inf file that I can remove.

I could, as a scorched earth policy, jump into OS X and just delete them from there, but I'm worried that this may cause me issues. I would much rather find the 'proper' way of doing it.

Comment: The "proper" way is to not manually delete the files in the FileReposity, hence it's trying to stop you from doing it. ;)  Anyhow, this definitely seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: have you ever tried my linked command/tool? 3 years after asking still no response from you is disappointing. Does it work or do you need more details?

Answer (score 46):

Don't delete the files with the Explorer. remove the drivers correctly with [pnputil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800798%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

- Open command prompt (`cmd.exe`) as admin and run `pnputil -e > C:\drivers.txt`

  [image]
- open the file drivers.txt and look which .inf file is associated with
  the driver you want to remove
- run `pnputil.exe -d oem<NUMBER>.inf`

This removes the driver correctly. If this is too complicated, you can use the tool [DriverStore Explorer [RAPR]](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer)

[image]

Click on `enumerate`, select the driver and click on `Delete Package`.

Comment: Thanks! Just freed around 5 GB of space by deleting old NVidia drivers with this awesome RAPR tool.