# Win10: How can I delete driver files? (C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, permissions, administrator

**My situation and goal:**
I have a Asus Laptop which I upgraded from Win7 to Win10 a year ago. So far so good. My Account is since ever defined as administrator, but actually it can't proceed administrator tasks.

I want to delete driver files. The path is in the title of the question. My account is an administrator account but I can't delete files in this folder.

When I move files from folder A to folder B it happens that I have to confirm moving them or I have to give allowance to applications to install files. This experiences brought me to the point that I see something with the administrator rights is not correct. I assumed that my account has problems with the administrator rights and I have to fix these before I can delete the targeted files.

**What I tried to solve the administrator issue:**

I tried several ways to get administrator rights.

1) I tried to change account typ from standard to administrator. Not possible, because when I choose this option the button to accept the choice gets inactive.
button gets inactive when I select administrator. And as you can see the account is defined as administrator, but is from type standard.

[image]

2) I activated an administrator account via cmd-window and "net user administrator /active:yes". It worked but this account is not able delete files which need administrator rights. It seems this account is an administrator account but has not the rights for it.

3) I tried to change the administrator rights for my standard account and administrator account in "Save mode" of windows. the same situation like in point 1.

4) By solving the administrator issue, I found out that my windows lakes functionalities. I wanted to take control over this problem by using the "Computer Manager", but the area where you can manage accounts and group is not existing. The local group policy window doesn't work. (see below in the comments the screenshots)

Something in the system is messed up. What is wrong or what else can I do to make it possible to control this kind of files in Windows 10?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: ramound, thanks for you fast reply. i get your point. my account should have administrator rights and I can't give it again.

Comment: What can I do, when I can't delete a file, which needs administrator permission? This are more screenshots: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5903670/Bild%202.png https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5903670/Bild%203.png https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5903670/Bild%204.png https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5903670/Bild%205.png

Comment: don't delete files/folders directly, use this to remove old/bad drivers: http://superuser.com/a/597395/174557

Comment: Your question should be about the actual problem you're facing/trying to solve instead of about trying to give you Administrator user Administrator rights (as it already has it).   You've fallen into the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) trap.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Good point with the XY Problem. I will next time more carefully describe what is actually my problem. I will go threw the tips and hope I can solve everything.

Comment: I fixed my question and specified it. (Its my first time on super user. I have to get used to the precise way how you work here.) If you have further insights to understand the described issue, please share it.

Comment: What is the motivation for wanting to remove these driver files in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I move files from folder A to folder B it happens that I have to
> confirm moving them or I have to give allowance to applications to
> install files.

Depending on the specifics, the destination folder likely is a protected directory, which has required to elevate operation since Windows Vista.  **In other words, what you describe in this statement, is not abnormal in the slightest.**

> I tried to change account type from standard to administrator. Not
> possible, because when I choose this option the button to accept the
> choice gets inactive. button gets inactive when I select
> administrator. And as you can see the account is defined as
> administrator, but is from type standard.

The account in the screenshot is an Administrator.  **There is no evidence from the screenshots you provided that, the account depicted in the screenshots, is anything but an Administrator.**

> 3. I tried to change the administrator rights for my standard account
>    and administrator account in "Save mode" of windows. the same
>    situation like in point 1.

I think you actually mean **Safe Mode**, instead of **Save Mode**, but there is not evidence that your account is anything but an Administrator.

> 2. I activated an administrator account via cmd-window and "net user
>    administrator /active:yes". It worked but this account is not able
>    delete files which need administrator rights. It seems this account is
>    an administrator account but has not the rights for it.

Your conclusion is incorrect.  The built-in `Administrator` account has less restrictions then a user account that is created and placed in the `Administrator` user group.  The account in the screenshot is a member of this group.  **The built-in `Administrator` account, has all permissions that a user account that is created, which was placed in the Administrator user group has.**

The computer management on my workstation looks exactly like this:
[image]

You need to launch explorer.exe as an Administrator, and take ownership of the folder in question, if you want to delete the highlighted folder.  Of course you should NOT do this because your attempting to remove the folder and the driver contained within it the incorrect way.  Additionally having to escalated, the action to delete a protected directory like the one you have highlight, is actually normal behavior.

[image]

This behavior:

[image]

Typically happens when you don't have permissions to the folder.  Due to the location of the folder, only system accounts are given access to it, because they are not supposed to be deleted by hand.  If you still want to delete the folder, take ownership of the folder and add your user to the ACL, then escalate the permissions of explorer.exe and you can delete the folder.  **This again is not the suggest method of getting rid of this driver.  Once you take ownership of this file you WILL cause problems.  You still won't be able to delete it if Windows is using the driver.**

Conclusion: Your system does not appear to have any problems.  Your user account that exists is an Administrator.  **Everything you describe, and believe to be a problem, is actually normal Windows behavior.**

The correct way to remove drivers is the following:

> 1. Within an elevated command prompt run the following command:
>
>    **run pnputil -e > C:\drivers.txt**
> 2. Open the file drivers.txt and look which .inf file is associated with the driver you want to remove
> 3. run **pnputil.exe -d oem.inf**
>
> If you want an easier way to remove it.  You can use, [DriverStore
> Explorer [RAPR]](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer/releases), to enumerate the drivers then press delete.

Source: [How do I delete folders from the Windows 7 DriverStore?](https://superuser.com/questions/597370/how-do-i-delete-folders-from-the-windows-7-driverstore/597395#597395)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers Ramhound. from your answers I conclude that the administrator rights are not the issue and my account works fine. Instead I should focus on how to delete the target files. (sorry for not offering already the screenshots via imgur, but right now the registration is out of order)

Comment: @nefacio - The picture icon within edit mode for any question or answer uploads pictures to the location I suggested.  We just needed the links.  Be sure you upvote magicandre1981's answer to the link question, since that actually, is the solution to your problem.

Comment: thank you for your endurance and uploading the screenshots. I made a bundle of mistakes while using this platform. (Was my first question posted) I see now that the answer from magicandre1981 is the one to follow. I can upvote your answer but the answer from magicandre1981 has no arrow to upvote. If you can give me a hint how to upvote his answer, I would be glad.

Comment: It's the answer with 22 votes: http://superuser.com/questions/597370/how-do-i-delete-folders-from-the-windows-7-driverstore/597395#597395

Comment: DriverStore Explorer [RAPR] was the answer for me but that URL is no longer correct. You can download it from https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer/releases