# How to remove redundant compatible device drivers on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, drivers, hard-drive-recovery, display-driver

I just experienced a failed video driver installation for Intel HD Graphics driver on Windows 10.

The failed ones are still shown as the compatible hardware. See below:

[image]

I have rolled back to the old `10.18.15`. But I don't want to keep the `20.19.xx` ones. So how to remove them?

Comment: use pnputil to remove old drivers: http://superuser.com/a/597395/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, this should be better than my approach. Btw, any way to backup a driver's files?

Comment: dism can export drivers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/dism-driver-servicing-command-line-options-s14

Comment: @magicandre1981 Could you change your comment into a reply so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the old drivers with [pnputil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800798%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

- run `pnputil -e > C:\drivers.txt`

  [image]
- open the file drivers.txt and look which .inf file is associated with
  the driver you want to remove
- run `pnputil.exe -d oem<NUMBER>.inf`

This removes the driver correctly. If this is too complicated, you can use the tool [DriverStore Explorer [RAPR]](http://driverstoreexplorer.codeplex.com/)

[image]

Click on `enumerate`, select the driver and click on `Delete Package`.

If you want to export your currently drivers you can use [DISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/dism-driver-servicing-command-line-options-s14)

```
DISM /Online /Export-Driver /Destination:C:\destpath
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Take the steps below:

1. Install the driver you want to **uninstall**.
2. Right click the device and select **Uninstall** from the context menu.
3. Check the `Delete the driver software for this device` in the pop up window.
4. Reboot (as necessary)

Below is what it looks like after I kill one of the `20.19.xx` driver.

[image]