# Uninstall a certain Windows update

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-update

I got this update and would prefer to uninstall it.

```
Intel - System - 3/13/2016 12:00:00 AM - 11.0.0.1010
```

Thing is, I can't find the hardware it is related to in Control Panel -> Device Manager, so I can't roll it back. Searching the registry for the driver `ICCWDT`, it seems to be related to `ACPI`. One entry showed that the the `MatchingDeviceId` is `acpi\int3f0d` and it seems to be called Intel Watchdog Timer Driver. I see no references to that in startup or services (using `msconfig`).

Was it an update that installed a driver that was not relevant to my machine, so there is nothing I need to do to "undo" this update?

Comment: use DriverStore Explorer [RAPR] to remove drivers: http://superuser.com/a/597395/174557

Comment: are you saying this is something i would have to remove completely and cannot just rollback like other drivers? thanks.

Comment: this was a mistake from MS. they pushed it out to all users: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.borncity.com%2Fblog%2F2017%2F01%2F05%2Fwindows-78-1-intel-system-treiber-updates-mit-bsen-kollateralschden%2F&edit-text=