# Can I delete amdkmpfd.ini package in Windows 10?

Tags: amd-radeon, windows-10-upgrade, display-driver, windows-10-v1511

I am having a dell-inspiron-15r-7520(SE) Laptop.
The laptop is currently running Windows 10 Version 1511 OS Build 10586.1176.
The laptop comes with AMD Radeon HD 7730M discrete graphics card.

My problem is I cant Update my laptop to newer version as Update fails cause of AMD Radeon Driver.

I have disabled installation of Device & driver from multiple places including
"Group Policy" & "Registry", post which I Disabled & Uninstalled the device & driver respectively.
But on the next reboot the device get re-installed.
So I downloaded RAPR.exe and checked that even after Un-Installing everything still one package remains amdkmpfd.ini.
I think this is the local package through which the System is able to recognize & re-install the device.

PS:-
I have already tried updating the driver to latest version but it didn't work,
Treid downloading the latest Drivers directly from AMD site but even it didn't work in both the cases Windows Update fails.

So my question is What if I remove the amdkmpfd.ini package?
Will my system become unstable cause I think its related to "Amdkmpfd.sys" which acts as a filter driver for the installed graphics card.

Link :- http://www.freefixer.com/library/file/amdkmpfd.sys-90599/

Comment: If you can do a full system image backup and then perform the change, you could confirm if it makes the system unstable.The backout plan would be to push the image backup back to the HD accordingly. Obviously you'd need to understand the restore process.

Comment: @Facebook that's the last option I always have, but wanted to determine if someone else has tried this and succeeded or failed.

Comment: uninstall the driver/GPU in device manager and try to upgrade to 1709

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried uninstalling but some how after un-Installing, the moment I restart the lappy some default drivers are installed by the OS, even though installing drivers and device is restricted from multiple places as mentioned above. I am thinking of installing the latest drivers from AMD website again, I tried that earlier but it didn't help, will give it a shot again.

Comment: since Win10 there are no inbox default drivers for GPUs. so the driver will always be downloaded. [disable automatic driver update](https://superuser.com/q/964475/174557)

Comment: also try [DriverStore Explorer](https://superuser.com/a/597395/174557) to remove the AMD driver. Now get [the 1709 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount it run setup.exe and upgrade with internet connection disabled.

Comment: @magicandre1981 As I have mentioned in my question I am already using the Driver Store exe(RAPR.exe)  "I downloaded RAPR.exe and checked that even after Un-Installing everything still one package remains amdkmpfd.ini."

Comment: use [DDU to uninstall the driver](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=915) completely

Comment: have you tried DDU to get rid of the driver and all related files? does upgrade now work fine?

Comment: Yes I tried DDU and removed all the drivers and after that the only thing remaining was the file mentioned in my Question. However Upgrade worked finally after doing multiple things, like disabling automatic update of drivers, uninstalling the driver and finally disabling the Graphic card from device manager.

Comment: ok, post all steps you did in an answer and accept it later